# Number of light bulbs to light a cubical room to a certain number of lumens

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling

Consider a cubical room of edge $l$ with light bulbs which can be placed on any of the faces (imagine they are point size). For a given light bulb, the lumens produced decreases with inverse square of the distance from the bulb . Given that each bulb produces $x$ lumens, how many bulbs are required to light each point in the room to a minimum of $y$ lumen.

Source: Something I came up with

#### My thoughts:

If we have $n$ bulbs, and consider a point $z$ inside the cube where distances from each bulb is $\{r_i \}$ then we find that the total lumens at $z$ is :

$$L(z) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x}{r_i^2}$$

I think the optimal place to place a bulb would be the center of a face, and that if  $ y \leq \frac{x}{l^2}$, then obviously just one bulb is enough. But, the problem becomes a lot more complicated when $y$ exceeds $\frac{x}{l^2}$.

Comment: If you put one lamp at the centre of a face, then the distance to the vertices of the opposite face is a little bit more than $l$, namely $l\sqrt{6}/2$. Note that such a lamp will in reality hardly light up the wall it is in because all the light is going parallel to the wall. To model that I think you'd have to look at lux instead of lumen for each of the walls.

Comment: Why is lux better than lumens @JaapScherphuis

Comment: As I said, it depends on what you're modelling, what aspect you find important. What you have now just sums up the light coming from all directions equally. If you had a small black speherical object anywhere in your room, it would be absorbing at least $ry$ amount of light energy where $r$ is some constant depending on the size of the object. For non-spherical objects, you don't have such a constant $r$. Instead it depends on how much of a cross-sectional area it presents to each light. [...continued in next comment]

Comment: A wall (or section of a wall) at a shallow angle to the light will then have a smaller cross-sectional area than if it were perpendicular to the incoming light. It receives an amount proportional to $\sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the wall and the light rays. A proportion of the incoming light is scattered by the surface and determines how bright the wall looks. This is given by how much each part of the surface gives out, so is measured in lumen/m^2=lux. The point is that if you want to illuminate the walls rather than objects, then you have to take angles into account.

Comment: Oh, I want the whole room being some amount of lumens @JaapScherphuis